# Calculating confidence interval of a regression prediction

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

My output for confidence intervals for a given value of a prediction using regression show difference when I use different calculators. Eg, the following website:

http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calculator.aspx?id=90

I get:
[image]

However, using `interval="confidence"` in predict(), I get

[image]

How would I resolve this difference? What is the proper way of calculating the confidence interval for a prediction?

P.S. (As an add on question, say I have 2 predicted values, and calculated the ratio of them. Would I have to divide the confidence interval as well, or would I add them?)

Thank you! :)

Comment: With regard to the first question prediction is different from estimation.  So the confidence intervals will be wider for the same confidence level. As for the two predictions in the second output, you don't show the confidence levels.  As for the second question I don't see why you would take a ratio of the predictions and neither adding nor dividing the intervals makes any sense.

Comment: Hey @MichaelChernick thanks for your reply, what do you mean you dont show the confidence intervals? isn't the lwr and upr the 95% confidence interval?

Comment: The second question was more of a "what if". Say I had 2 predictions, and their confidence intervals. If i had to take the ratio of them, what would the final confidence interval be?